# Form is not submiting after the sweet alert confirmation

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm having a table which contains some rows of data and I have delete button for each row.

My form is not submiting if I implement sweetalert2 with my code, what I need is, I need to delete my row only after sweet alert confirmation button.
Here is my Code;

```html
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($category_details as $category_detail): ?>
<tr>
<td>...</td> <!-- etc -->
<form method="post">
<td>

<input type="hidden" name="delete-id" value="<?php echo $category_detail['id']; ?>">

<button type="submit" name="single-cdelete" class="swa-confirm btn btn-trash-alt">
<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
</button>

</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
</form>
```

```html
if(isset($_POST['single-cdelete'])){
    $delete_id    = $_POST['delete-id'];
    $delete_image = $_POST['delete-image'];
    category_delete($delete_id, $delete_image);
}

function category_delete($delete_id, $delete_image){
    
    global $db;

    if(mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM categories WHERE id =$delete_id")){
        unlink('../assets/images/categories/'.$delete_image);
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Category has been deleted successfully";
    }else{
        $_SESSION['success'] ="Something went wrong, Try again";
    }
}
```

**My SweetAlert Code:**

```html
<script>
$(".swa-confirm").on("click", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault(); 

        Swal.fire({
            title: "Are you Sure ?",
            text:"You want to Delete the selected Category",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#cc3f44",
            confirmButtonText: "Delete",
            closeOnConfirm: true,
            html: false
        }, function( confirmed ) {
            if( confirmed ){
                $('.swa-confirm').submit();
            }
        });

});
</script>
```

Comment: not familiar with the sweetalert but it looks like you need to make an ajax call to the php code to make wire up your delete function onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the comment from **@Tangoabc Delta** you just can use .submit() event on a form, so :

- first, give your form an id :

  ```
  <form method="post" id="swaForm">
  ```
- then use the script like this :

  ```
   <script>
        $(".swa-confirm").on("click", function(e) {

                e.preventDefault(); 

                Swal.fire({
                    title: "Are you Sure ?",
                    text:"You want to Delete the selected Category",
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "#cc3f44",
                    confirmButtonText: "Delete",
                    closeOnConfirm: true,
                    html: false
                }).then(function() {
                       $('#swaForm').submit();
                    })
                });
        </script>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

As it's evident from your code, you've used jQuery to perform a form submission.

As per the documentation, https://api.jquery.com/submit/, the method `.submit()` can only be used on a `form`.

> The **submit event** is sent to an element when the user is attempting **to submit a form**. It can ***only be attached to `<form>` elements***..
>
> Forms can be submitted either by clicking an explicit , , or , or by
> pressing Enter when certain form elements have focus...

It can be seen that you're also relying on some other functionality `Swal.fire(..)` because of which, you had to do an `event.preventDefault()`, otherwise, the form would have submitted itself without hassle. But it's understandable that you will need this part of functionality.

So, to solve your problem, you need to add some kind of **identifier** to your **form** e.g. a `class` or an `id`. So, instead of doing this:

```
<form method="post">
```

..do, something like

```
<form method="post" id="myform">
```

..and in the code snippet, use this identifier to call `submit()`:

**update**: Also, notice that `sweetalert2` supports a `promise`, and therefore, will recommend using a *`then`-able* promise and use a `catch` block to track any errors.

```
$(".swa-confirm").on("click", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  Swal.fire({
      ...
    }).then((confirmed) => {
      if (confirmed) {
        $('#myform').submit(); // << here
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
});
```

Comment: I've tried your code but It's not submiting...Don't know why

Comment: need to provide form information, like HTML or PHP code snapshots for better understanding.

Comment: Try 3 things here: 



1. Try removing that `preventDefault` (in this case, you won't need this submit()`

2. Try that `submit()` call outside the callback (the `preventDefault` can stay)

3. Put a debug-point and see if the `Swal` API's callback is reachable or not. I think, there's some error in the `swal` which is preventing it from occuring.